# cloudera/quickstart image running in docker container is not starting and status is exited(139). How to solve it?

Tags: linux, docker, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I'm using WSL2 with Ubuntu distro, and I was trying create a container in Docker with the Following command:
`docker run --hostname=quickstart.cloudera --privileged=true -t -i -p 8888:8888 -p 7180:7180 -p 81:80 4239cd2958c6 /usr/bin/docker-quickstart` 
[cloudera hadoop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5sZa.jpg)

I have also created .wslconfig file and included these 2 lines
[wsl2]
kernelCommandLine = vsyscall=emulate

Is there any solution to this problem ?

I downloaded the image from https://hub.docker.com/r/cloudera/quickstart
and then when I'm starting my container so it is showing Exited(139)

I'm expecting it to run all the servies of cloudera like Hue and cloudera manager